# Is it possibile to create a text label without using OnGUI?

Tags: text, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm creating a app in Unity which is quite text heavy. So far, all the text is handled through the OnGUI function. I think I'm going to run into problems later on.

So, is it possible to create text, (using true type fonts, not 3D text or bitmaps. Not using something from the assets store either!) without using OnGUI? If so, how do you make each of the text filds independent with different styles, positions & parents?

Comment: Use something like NGUI.  There's a lot more options and the performance is a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

Check the AssetStore for 2D toolkit or NGui plugin,  they are both great for Ui stuff
they contain nice ways to do gradients, fonts, and aligning to screen edges or parent handles

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be Daikonforge:
http://www.daikonforge.com/dfgui/

The company I work for released a game using NGUI, not long ago, but we are switching to Daikonforge now, because it's deemed more Artist-friendly than NGUI.